# Create `FUNCTION` that loads data from an URL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a function that takes the url as parameter, executes the `curl` command and returns the loaded data. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_content_from_url(url text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN PROGRAM 'curl ' + url;
END
$$;
```

Is this possible?
How do I accomplish this?

I also tried following `plsh` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION load_file_content (text) RETURNS text AS '
#!/bin/bash
curl $1
' LANGUAGE plsh;
```

But I get following error result when I execute `SELECT load_file_content('http://...');`:

```
ERROR:  load_file_content:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 20745  100 20745    0     0   669k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  675k
SQL state: XX000
```

And following plperl function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION load_file_content (text) RETURNS text AS $$
  my $result = "";
  my $result .= qx(curl $1);
  return $result;
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

Which results in following error when trying to create the function:

```
ERROR:  'quoted execution (``, qx)' trapped by operation mask at line 3.
```

Comment: Write a function in PL/Perl or PL/Python.

Comment: How can I construct a curl command ('curl' + url) in a pl/perl function?

Comment: Call it with [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This is what your linked site says: This is not what you want to use to capture the output from a command; for that you should use merely backticks or qx//, as described in `STRING` in perlop.

Comment: Do that then. `curl` has a `-o` option to save the output to file.

Comment: You should use `plperlu` - the untrusted version of the language. In trusted `plperl` the function is blocked because it gets data from the file system or net.

Comment: Can you try with `curl -s $1` ?

Comment: With curl -s $1 I get ERROR:  script exited with status 6

Comment: `COPY` could be used to load a table: `CREATE TABLE iris(sepal_length numeric, sepal_width numeric, petal_length numeric, petal_width numeric, class text);  COPY iris FROM PROGRAM 'curl https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data | sed "s/^$/\\\./g"' WITH DELIMITER ',';`  Then you can have a function to query the table.  Can manage the table dynamically or possibly as a temp table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION load_file_content (text) RETURNS text AS '
#!/bin/bash
curl $1 2>/dev/null
' LANGUAGE plsh;
```